# Can't run AutoHotKey .exe using python

Tags: python

I have a python script that I am wanting to use to run an AHK `.exe` in a loop.
I have written the basic code to test it out. However I cannot get python to actually launch the `.exe`

I only have basic python experience so nothing too complex or explanations if it needs to be.

The code is:

```
import os
import time
print("Starting")
time.sleep(5)
print("Running")
os.system("F:/Macro/auto.exe")
```

The python script and `.exe` are in the same folder.

The code currently runs, prints correctly but closes without any evidence of running the `.exe`.

I tried using a `.bat` to do this but that did not work either.

Anyone know why? Cheers

Comment: Check its return value to see whether it run successfully. Also, it's recommended to use `subprocess` module rather that `os.system()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what a return value is.

Comment: @Ethan Wilson `x = os.system("F:/Macro/auto.exe")`, then `x` is the return value

Comment: Alright for whatever reason just using the `subprocess` module and `subprocess.run("F:/Macro/auto.exe")` it now works. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Using `import subprocess` and `subprocess.run("F:/Macro/auto.exe")` fixed the issue. Thanks to @h4z3